# Firebase integration with Google Cloud Natural Language API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am using a prototype application using Firebase. What my Android app is doing is scanning gmail emails (My account for testing) and I want insights for example to understand when to offer meetings. When to offer new tasks to the user etc... I want the machine to really understand the emails. Basically an AI app.

So the first part of the app is scanning the body of the emails and extract the text from each email.

Second part is to upload the text to the Firebase storage for analysis.

Is there a way to integrated the Firebase with Google Cloud Natural Language API?
 Or to directly connect it with the Google Cloud Natural Language API using REST?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK no direct integration with Firebase, but there's a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/) and an [RPC API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rpc/), and [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/libraries) for C#, GO, JAVA, NODE.JS, PHP, PYTHON & RUBY

One of them is bound to suit your needs...